# If $A$ and $A^\perp$ are closed then $A\oplus A^\perp=B$ for a Banach space $B$

Tags: banach-spaces, orthogonality, direct-sum

Let $b$ be a **bounded, positive definite** and **symmetric bilinear** form on a Banach space $B$.

I want to prove the following:

Let $A\subset B$ be a closed subspace such that $A^\perp$ is closed too. Then $B=A\oplus A^\perp$. $(A^\perp=\{x\in B\vert b(x,a)=0\,\forall a\in A\})$

---

Clearly $A\cap A^\perp=0$ since $b$ is positive definite. But how can I prove that $A+A^\perp = B$? Would it help if i knew that $A + A^\perp$ is closed?

---

Edit: **Its wrong**. Counter example in the answer and here: [When does $A^⊥=0$
imply that $A=X$
for a subspace $A⊂X$
of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654265/when-does-a-perp-0-imply-that-a-x-for-a-subspace-a-subset-x-of-a-banach)

Comment: What does $A^\perp$ mean in Banach spaces?

Comment: @WilliamM. Orthogonal with repect to $b$. Added it to the question.

Comment: So your Banach space also has an inner product... So Hilbert space actually.

Comment: As written in the first line of the question. But its not necessarily a Hilbert space. The norm does not have to be induced from $b$. (Sure $b$ defines another norm on $B$, but this norm does not have to be complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is false. Consider the Banach space $B = (\ell^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and let $$b(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n x_ny_n, \qquad x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty, y = (y_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^2.$$
Let $$A = \left\{y = (y_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1ny_n = 0\right\}.$$
Then $A$ is a closed subspace and $A^\perp = \{0\}$ is also a closed subspace but $A \dotplus A^\perp = A \subsetneq \ell^2$.