# When does $A^\perp = 0$ imply that $A=X$ for a subspace $A\subset X$ of a Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, orthogonality, direct-sum

**Setup**

Consider the Banach space $X=\mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R^n)$ with norm
$$
\|f\|=\sup |f|+\sup |\dot f|.
$$
This banach space has a symmetric bilinear positive definite form
$$
b(f,g)=\int_0^1\langle f,g\rangle.
$$
Here $\langle \bullet,\,\bullet\rangle$ is the standard scalar product $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.
By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, $b$ is also continuous. We set
$$
A^\perp=\{ f\in X| b(f,a)=0\,\forall a\in A \}
$$
for every subset $A\subset X$.

**Question** Let $A\subset X$ be a linear subspace. Under what conditions on $A$ do we have the following implication
$$
A^\perp = 0 \implies A=X.
$$

**Ansatz** Say that $A$ has property 1 if $A$ is closed and for every linear bounded functional $\lambda:X\to \mathbb R$ that does not extend to a bounded functional on the completion $\bar X =L^2([0,1],\mathbb R^n)$ there exists some $f\in A$ such that $\lambda(f) \neq 0$.

*Conjecture*: Let $A\subset X$ be a linear subspace that has property 1. Then $A^\perp =0\implies A=X$.

---

**Examples** Consider the evaluation maps $ev_t:X\to \mathbb R^n$ for $t\in[0,1]$. They are all bounded so that $X_t:=\ker ev_t$ is closed. These are *proper* subspaces with $X_t^\perp = 0$. And they do not have property 1.

**But... why??**: I want to know under which conditions we have splittings
$$
X=B\oplus B^\perp
$$
for closed supspaces $B\subset X$ for which $B^\perp$ is closed too. Turns out that closedness of both of these sets is not enough (the $X_t$ are counter examples). $B\cap B^\perp=0$ is clear but $B+ B^\perp = X$ is wrong, we only have that $(B+ B^\perp)^\perp=0$. Hence my question: When does $A^\perp = 0$ imply $A=X$ (Especially for $A=B+ B^\perp$)

Comment: You haven't defined $\langle f,g\rangle$

Comment: Also, to render $\langle f,g\rangle$ correctly in MathJax you need to use `\langle,\rangle` for the angled brackets

Comment: Since the completion of $X$ with respect to $b$ is $Y=L^2([0,1], \Bbb{R}^n)$, $A^\perp$ can be calculated as $A^\perp_Y \cap X$, where $A^\perp_Y$ is the orthogonal complement of $A$ in $Y$. In your examples, the space $X_t$ has $(X_t)^\perp = 0$ because it is dense in $Y$, and I don't think "zero detection" has much to do with your question.

Comment: If you don't require $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A=\mathcal{C}^2([0,1],\mathbb R^n)$ detects zero and has $A^\perp = 0$, but $A \ne X$. For closed counter-examples, you can choose $A=\ker (ev_0 + ev_1)$.

Comment: These are very good points; Thanks! Oh boy, one really has to work to split a Banach space...

Comment: I also listed closed counter-examples in my last comment. Actually, choose any linear functional $f$ that is continuous in $X$, does not belong to $ev_t$ and can not be extended to a continuous linear functional in $Y$, $A=\ker f$ is a closed counter-example that detects zero.

Comment: I replaced "for every $ev_t$" with "for every bounded functional that does not extend to the completion". Any hope then? And Is there some description of these functionals?